# Adding iCloud Drive File Manager to App - iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, icloud

I want to support adding files to iCloud within my iOS Application. I want these files to be added to a folder on iCloud Drive (e.g. like the Numbers or Pages folders). I tried everything I found online about this subject but I did not manage to add a folder to iCloud Drive.

First, I added `NSUbiquitousContainers` to the info.plist

```
<key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key>
<dict>
    <key>iCloud.com.<xyz>.AppName</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
        <string>App Name</string>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
        <string>Any</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

After this, I added the iCloud capability to my app:
[image: iCloud capability]

Then, I added the following code to my ViewController:

```
if let iCloudDocumentsURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents") {
    if (!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: iCloudDocumentsURL.path, isDirectory: nil)) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: iCloudDocumentsURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: after setting breakpoints I discovered that the code after `if (!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: iCloudDocumentsURL.path, isDirectory: nil)) {` never gets called. I temporarily removed this line, but this did not do anything*.

Finaly, I added a file using the following code:

```
//Save text file to local directory
let file = "file.txt" //Text file to save to iCloud
let text = "sample text" //Text to write into the file
func saveToDirectory(){
    guard let directory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
    let fileURL = directory.appendingPathComponent(file)

    print(directory)
    //Writing
    do {
        try text.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
    } catch {
        /* error handling here */
        print("Error in writing")
    }

    //Reading
    do {
        let getText = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
        print(getText)
    } catch {
        /* error handling here */
        print("Error in reading")
    }
}
```

I do not see the app's folder, or the above file appear on my iCloud Drive. But when I download the apps container and look at it's contents I see the file listed under `/AppData/Documents`.

Did someone else got this? And/or does someone know how to solve this?

Thanks!

*I also changed the Build/Version numbers of my app, but without any result*

Answer (score 0):

You should copy your file to iCloud container, you are writing it to app sandbox only.

First, create `Documents` folder on your iCloud container  - if you store file in other folder, your app on another device will see the folder but it won't appear in Files app.

Then copy your file.txt into `Documents` folder on your iCloud container.